# issue animating the react navigation native stack header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

### What I want

I'm trying to animate the [react navigation native stack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator) header by changing the background from a **transparent** to a **gray** color when the user scrolls down. I was reading the documentation and it suggests using the [navigation.setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component) to interact with the screen info.

I am using [react-native-reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedScrollHandler/) to capture the scroll value and change it when the user interacts with the screen.

### The problem

I'm capturing the scroll value and using it inside the `setOptions` method but it doesn't work, it just doesn't execute the changes.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
  useSharedValue,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const MyScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const scrollY = useSharedValue(0);
  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
    onScroll: (e) => {
      scrollY.value = e.contentOffset.y;
    },
  });


  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: scrollY.value > 0 ? 'black' : 'transparent',
      },
      headerTransparent: scrollY.value === 0,
    });
  }, [ navigation, scrollY.value ]);
}
```

### Deps

```bash
"react-native": "0.67.2",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
```

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to animate the Native Stack header, but since only `Animated` components accept animated styles in Reanimated 2, you'd probably have to create a new component for the header (an `Animated.Something`)...

We can achieve this by using the `header` option, which can be found [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#header).

A simple example built with Expo:

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
  interpolateColor,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },

  item: {
    padding: 20,
    margin: 15,
    backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
  },

  header: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    padding: 15,
    borderColor: "whitesmoke",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },

  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});

function WelcomeScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const translationY = useSharedValue(0);

  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
    translationY.value = event.contentOffset.y;
  });

  const aStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    backgroundColor: interpolateColor(
      translationY.value,
      [0, 50],
      ["white", "skyblue"],
      "RGB"
    ),
  }));

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      header: () => (
        <Animated.View style={[styles.header, aStyle]}>
          <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Testing</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      ),
    });
  }, [aStyle, navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.ScrollView onScroll={scrollHandler} scrollEventThrottle={16}>
        {Array(15)
          .fill(0)
          .map((_, index) => (
            <View style={styles.item} key={`${index}`}>
              <Text>Item {`${index}`}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
      </Animated.ScrollView>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen component={WelcomeScreen} name="Welcome" />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Note that in this example, we're passing an `Animated.View` to the `header` option, passing our animated style (`aStyle`) to it as a style.

Also, just like you did, I'm using `useAnimatedScrollHandler` to track the scroll position, and interpolating (with `interpolateColor`) the `backgroundColor` of the header accordingly (between 'white' and 'skyblue', so it's easier to visualize).

Uploaded this example to this [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@joaocout/headeranimation) so you can easily test it if you want.

I Hope this helps you solve your problem!

Comment: I'm getting this issue adding your suggested implementation: `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.` it is difficult to share all actual component code but the error is throwing when I use the `header` property inside `setOptions`... if I set any other property, this error is not thrown.

Comment: Usually, this happens when we make state changes repeatedly, and consequently, multiple re-renders happen.
Does your header component update any state?